# Open data for international treaties

Tags: data-request, legal

Are there data sources listing international treaties held between countries of the world? From treaties between 2 countries, up to treaties among dozens of countries. The status of the treaty, ratification and adoption details would be valuable details to have.

Comment: http://www.law.nyu.edu/library/research/foreign_intl/internationaltreaties/index.htm

Comment: http://www.paulhensel.org/dataintl.html

Comment: I hope someone comes and expands the valuable stuff in the links I provided into a full-blown answer.

Comment: Ted, in a few days please feel free to compile the answer from the exact sources you used. This way, people will be able to find valuable info in the future. In particular, dyadic data on countries and membership in multilateral treaties. If you can put a combined open dataset on the Web, so much the better.

Comment: The links you provided -especially the first one- are fairly straightforward in terms of looking up a treaty by search queries, and exporting to csv. So sure, I'll re-post those links with some explanation in a few days, unless someone else does first.

Answer (score 4):

A searchable directory of international treaties can be found here: http://www.worldtreatyindex.com/index.html

Links to download the raw data of the complete database can be found here:
http://www.worldtreatyindex.com/multi.html

Comment: Do you know under which license this database is published? Is it Open Data? Couldn't find anything on their website. Also, it seems that the download only includes multilateral treaties and not bilateral ones -- or am I mistaken?